# How we can Sort ArryMap in Android

Tags: java, android

I am using ArrayMap in my Activity for storing my response. 
`ArrayMap<String, PublicSpotData> publicSpotData` ArrayMap will store index as well as key-value pair. Now I have problem in sorting ArrayMap. I want to sort ArrayMap according to `publicSpotData.getAt() (int)`. 
I have already done this.

`List<Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData> entry : publicSpotData.entrySet()) {
       entries.add(entry);
 }`

```
 Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData> o1, Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData> o2) {
                    return o2.getValue().getAt().compareTo(o1.getValue().getAt());
                }
            });

            for (Map.Entry<String, PublicSpotData> entry : entries)
                publicSpotData.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());`
```

But this not solved my issue. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Won't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java) be useful?

Comment: I already use this. But this is only update key, value pair, not index. that's why. It's not getting sort

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Collections#sort** [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(c), aComparator);
```

c is just a [key set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html#keySet()) from the ArrayMap
and aComparator is a custom implemetation of comparator to sort the elemets in the map

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help. He doesn't want to sort on the keys, he wants to sort the whole thing based on a property of a map value.

Comment: Sir, i have already done this. but in arraymap, i also want to sort index

Answer (score 1):

You can sort **any** Java collection by providing a **[Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)**.

In other words: you have to create a class that knows how to compare two *PublicSpotData* objects; and then you use that with [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Meaning: as long as your "incoming" object implements one of the Java collection interfaces (and the Android ArrayMap is a Map, which is a collection); you can sort it using the default means of the java library.

But then, the problem is more complicated: you can only sort **Lists**. And your input data ... is represented as Map. So, lets go step by step:

```
List<PublicSpotData> dataObjects = ... coming from somewhere
Collections.sort(dataObjects, new Comparator<PublicSpotData>() { ...
  here you put the comparator for that thing);
```

Now you got a list that is sorted for that criteria.

In that sense: the **real** problem is that your model doesn't support your needs. The essence of a Map is to provide that **mapping** functionality. 
You need to:

- extract a list of data objects
- sort those
- iterate the sorted list; and for each entry ... find the corresponding map key!

Comment: I have updated my Question. But Comparator is not solving this issue

Comment: I updated my answer in the meantime; as I figured that myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ArrayMap implements sorting implicitly for keys.

**Baseline: You need to iterate the arrayMap to obtain Key by index. then call value by that key.**

Here is an example of that. I list sorted outputs from unsorted inputs. then I sort the sort the keySet reversely.

```
ArrayMap<String, String> arrayMap = new ArrayMap<>();
        arrayMap.put("AAA7", "BBB2");
        arrayMap.put("AAA8", "BBB1");
        arrayMap.put("AAA9", "BBB");
        arrayMap.put("AAA9", "BBB");// will override previous call

        String res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMap.size(); i++) {
            String key = arrayMap.keyAt(i);
            res += arrayMap.get(key) + ", ";
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "normal output: " + res);

        // sorting array based on keys
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(arrayMap.keySet());
        java.util.Collections.reverse(list);//or you implement your own sort

        String res2 = "";
        for (String key : list) {
            res2 += arrayMap.get(key) + ", ";
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "output of sorted collection in reverse based on keys: " + res2);
```

For more efficiency, you might use `SimpleArrayMap` if you don't need standard Java API like Iteration.